# SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected

Tags: java, android, xmpp

Использую Smack для обмена сообщениями, пытаюсь подключится к серверу и отправить сообщение другому пользователю , получаю `SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected`. Подскажите, что может быть не так?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PORT = 5222;
    private static final String HOST = "jabber.ru";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("IrynaKanivets", "wasder13Luckygirl");
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        configBuilder.setResource("SomeResource");
        configBuilder.setServiceName("jabber.ru");
        configBuilder.setHost(HOST);
        configBuilder.setPort(PORT);
        AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());

// Connect to the server
        try {
            connection.connect();
            connection.login();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("Luckygirl@jabber.ru", new ChatMessageListener() {
            public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                Log.e("Received message: ", String.valueOf(message));
            }
        });

        try {
            newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
           Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(e));
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А Вы посмотрите чуть Выше в LogCat и увидите синими цветом стек-трейс, который будет содержать строку:

```
The following addresses failed: 'jabber.ru:5222' failed because android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

которая говорит о том, что Вы пытаетесь работать с сетью в UI-потоке, чего делать нельзя.

Comment: @post-zeew Спасибо, вы правы!